# Looking for feedback for LiPo based power supply circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, lipo

I try to design a LiPo powered circuit that should meet the following requirements:

- Undervoltage protection
- Overvoltage protection
- Reverse polarity protection
- Battery voltage measurement
- Push button to enable the device and keep it on by using a self-holding circuit
- Monitor the button state with an MCU
- Minimal current consumption (few µA)

I have designed the following circuit to fulfill the requirements.

[image]

But I´m not completely sure if this circuit will meet the requirements.

The part around the `BQ2961` is for battery protection and based on [this](https://forum.digikey.com/t/simple-undervoltage-and-overcurrent-protection-for-lithium-ion-and-lithium-polymer-batteries/13123) circuit from Digikey. I´m pretty confident that this part will do its job without any issue. Same for the battery measurement circuit on the right site and the reverse polarity protection.

But I´m unsure if the self-holding + button state monitoring will work without an issue.

What do you think about this circuit? Do you have any advice to improve this circuit?

Comment: Have you considered that simulation might help you figure this out yourself?

Comment: Good point. I´m not quite familiar with tools like LTSpice, but I will try it in the meantime.